# Send an Object to Vue from PHP

Tags: php, object, vue.js

I'm trying to set an extra css class for my object. In my props I have

```
customClass: {
        type: Object,
        default: function () {
            return {};
        },
    },
```

and I'm trying to set my customClass (custom-class) in my PHP code as such:

```
$('.ac-col-12.tokenizer-wrapper')
    .append('<tokenizer-wrapper :value=\'<?= json_encode($visit['tags']) ?>\' ' +
    'custom-class=\'{tag-visit}\''+
    'term=\'search\' label=\'<?= t('Tags'); ?>\' position=\'top\'>' +
"</tokenizer-wrapper>");
```

But I'm not passing the custom-class as a correct object so I'm receiving:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "customClass". Expected Object, got String.
```

How can I send the custom-class as object? suggestions?

Comment: You're missing the leading `:` on your `custom-class` attribute in the `append()` call.

Comment: @JohnEllmore but when I add : I have error: invalid expression: Unexpected token - in

    {tag-visit}

Comment: @Phiter cuz I have to? lol

Comment: @NickyMirfallah well, `{tag-visit}` isn't a valid JS object. Try replacing it with a valid object.

Comment: Is this really the only way? XD
Adding vue code with jQuery sounds like a nightmare that I wish I'll never have

Comment: @NickyMirfallah something like `{x: 1}` is a valid object. Maybe you meant to say something like `{"tag-visit": "somevalue"}`?

Comment: @JohnEllmore Thank you~ would you like to post this as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Phiter sometimes in a job you have to deal with bad/old code :D

Comment: I know exactly how that feels. Jesus christ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the leading `:` on your `custom-class` attribute in the `append()` call. Also, make sure you're passing in a valid object; maybe you meant `{"tag-visit": "somevalue"}` instead of `{tag-visit}`?